# Why do we need @Lookup, whats wrong with scope=prototype?

Tags: java, spring

I'm studying spring beans and came across @Lookup, it says:

> If we happen to decide to have a prototype Spring bean, then we are
>   almost immediately faced with the problem of how will our singleton
>   Spring beans access these prototype Spring beans?

hmm, I don't get it, because when I studied scope=prototype it says:

> 4.4.2 The prototype scope 
>   The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a
>   request for that specific bean is made

so it seems i misinterpreted the words:

> a request for that specific bean is made

actually programming in spring framework every line of the code is inside of some bean (i.e. @controller, @Service, etc), isn't it? 
And almost all of them are singletons, isn't it? 
So if I need prototype I just make scope=prototype and almost everytime it's injected to another bean (i.e. @controller, @Service, etc) isn't it?

So please give a real world scenarios, 1) when one should use @Lookup and 2) when it's not needed
Ok for the 1) the scenario:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SchoolNotification {
    // ... prototype-scoped state
}

@Component
public class StudentServices {

    // ... member variables, etc.

    @Lookup
    public SchoolNotification getNotification() {
        return null;
    }

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Please, show me scenario for the 2) case, and explain please the difference 
Thank u

Comment: For additional edification, the term you can use for further research is "method injection". Prior to the addition of the `@Lookup` annotation, the way to actually inject the singleton bean involved some very confusing syntax that involved making the singleton class abstract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implicit Bean scope in Spring is *Singleton*.
That means for a JVM instance, only a single instance of a Bean exists in memory (theoretically).

When you `@Autowire` a *Prototype*-scoped Bean inside a *Singleton*-scoped Bean, that *Prototype* one becomes a sort-of-singleton. Just think about it; a *Singleton* gets created, its injectable fields get *Autowired*, and that is it, the instance lives forever along with all its fields (keep in mind those *Prototype*-scoped fields are "pure" instances, they're not proxied).

---

```
@Lookup
```

is a *proxy-driven* annotation. What that means is Spring will extend your `class` using JDK proxies or CGLIB proxies, and it will override/implement the `@Lookup`-annotated method, providing its own version which uses a `BeanFactory#getBean` each time it is invoked.
The documentation is clear on this point

> An annotation that indicates 'lookup' methods, to be overridden by the
>   container to redirect them back to the `BeanFactory` for a `getBean` call.

Thus, that means a fresh Bean instance is returned every time.

---

Just for your knowledge, another approach for working with *Prototype*-scoped Beans inside
 "other"-scoped Beans is using [ProxyFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactoryBean.html). The only difference is that the proxy is created at configuration-time, and then made available for direct `@Autowire`ing, thus not requiring the definition of a `@Lookup` method, which sometimes is not wanted (usually by folks that are obsessed with clean code, like me).